# How to set custom NLS parameters for installation of oracle 12c on docker

Tags: oracle, docker, dockerfile, oracle12c

I want to install oracle 12c and create a database with following NLS parameters on docker using the oracle/docker-images.

```
### NLS settings
### ------------

nls_language = GERMAN
nls_territory = GERMANY
nls_currency = DM
nls_iso_currency = GERMANY
nls_numeric_characters = ",."
nls_date_format = DD.MM.YY
nls_date_language = GERMAN
nls_sort = GERMAN
```

I tried putting in the init.ora file and then build the image but that didnt help the cause.

It is still setting American as the default.

```
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY
NLS_CHARACTERSET
 WE8ISO8859P15
Character set

  NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS
  .,
  Numeric characters

  NAME
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  VALUE$
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  COMMENT$
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------

 NLS_ISO_CURRENCY
 AMERICA
 ISO currency

  NLS_CURRENCY
  $

NAME
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE$
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
COMMENT$
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
Local currency

NLS_TERRITORY
AMERICA
Territory

NLS_LANGUAGE

NAME
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE$
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 COMMENT$
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 AMERICAN
 Language
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you select `NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS` or `NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS`?

Comment: Thank you for the response . I am doing it using the image provided by oracle for docker installation. I am not sure how/where to tweak the docker installation to set these parameters.It is not a GUI. It is silent installation.

Comment: What @WernfriedDomscheit tried to suggest was that these parameters can be customized for session (=connection level). So it also depends on who is connecting to the database and how the client is setup.